# DB Table which sends data after which it removes the data from the table

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql, backend, godot

I don't know how to better put this in a one sentence question.
What I'm using: Postgresql, Express, React, Godot
What I want to do is the following: I've made a simple godot 3.3.2 game that upon compleation gives the user a reward which is done with a primitive random number generator method, afterwards the user data alongside his reward are sent and stored in the database.
However I do not want to hardcode this and I cannot limit how many items the game can giveout within the game. Is it possible to achieve this though a backend/db relation? 
Can I make a Table which would have rewards and send a random one all having different chances to the backend which would forward it to the game, display the user what he got and send it back to to a different table alongside his other information(I already have this part made) and remove the element sent from the column but keep the others?
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.  As written, your question is somewhere between trivial ("Yes") and too broad ("How do I implement a system?").

Comment: Have Godot send a request to the server asking for the reward. While it waits for a response have it play an animation or something. Let the server decide. Let the server update whatever tables it needs to update. And send a response to Godot. - *Whatever logic you need, as long as it is in the server, and it is not the client telling the server what the rewards is, then it is fine. I could go on how to expand it, or why not have Godot talk to the database, or why not encode the logic in the database… But I feel it would be stuffing for the answer.*

Comment: Learning how to phrase the business problem is a big part of becoming a better programmer. As it stands, I find it hard to picture what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Look: https://github.com/Marzin-bot/PostgreSQLClient
fontend postgres for GdScript

Samuel marzin